# Android, iPhone rear camera control

Tags: android, ios, swift, objective-c, react-native

I'm trying to figure out how to gain control of individual rear cameras available on latest android and iPhones. I can't seen to find much about this. If I can figure it out in the native code I'm hoping to integrate it in my react-native application.

It would be great if someone has any idea how this can be accomplished.

Answer (score 1):

I think that so far this is only achievable by [react-native-vision-camera](https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-vision-camera). This is the only module that allows you to specify with the camera device, virtual or physical, you can choose to take the photo with.

You can check out the docs [here](https://mrousavy.com/react-native-vision-camera/docs/guides/devices) on how to choose between camera devices.